# Can a lower core temperature, lower caloric intake and low blood pressure prolong life?

Tags: medical-science, life-expectancy

In Season 4, episode 8 of Torchwood: Miracle Day, a character is said to have prolonged their life (not much, but definitely longer) by keeping their core temperature two degrees lower than normal, maintaining a lower caloric intake, and keeping their blood pressure below 110 (I assume systolic pressure).

Is there actually any scientific evidence to validate this? I know it's a science fiction show, but they seemed to at least imply that this part was accurate in life.

Comment: Well... 'prolonged' as opposed to what? High caloric intake and high blood pressure will certainly shorten your lifespan, but do you mean higher than average? If so, the lower core temp is definitely out. Your body is 98F for a reason. Lower caloric intake? Maybe. Your body can be more efficient, but is less apt at fighting infections. Lower blood pressure? Haven't heard of it. Your heart adapts well up to a certain point. I'll answer later if nobody else has, but hopefully I gave you a head start.

Comment: [Effects of calorie restriction on life span in different organisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie_restriction#Effects_of_CR_on_life_span_in_different_organisms)

Comment: Coming back to this.  Lower than average, I assume. Obviously a higher blood pressure and intake is bad, but I've not seen anything on lower.  I did specify 110.  I too assume the temperate thing is wonky, but maybe in fahrenheit - definitely a bad thing in celsius.